# Javascript Map or immutable.js for ordered maps?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, immer.js

**I often find myself in the need of following**

- map structure for fast lookup
- should be iterable for processing, i.e. looping
- preserved order
- immutable

The tools at hand has pros and cons:

**Regular Javascript object**

- speedy lookups, **YES**
- immutable, **YES**, but it takes some care or the use of a library
- iterable, **kind of**, but bit fiddly via `Object.keys` or `.entries` or loop with `hasOwnProperty`

**Regular Javascript Map**

- speedy lookups, **YES**
- preserve order, **YES**
- iterable, **YES**
- immutable? **I don't know**. How do I clone a Map? Is is it slow to clone?

**Immutable.js Map**

- speedy lookups, **YES**
- preserve order, **YES**
- iterable, **YES**
- immutable, **YES**

**What to do?**
I actually like Immutable.js and I have used it in a very large project. But everyone is bashing on it and telling me to use Immer instead. Will Immer solve my needs stated above? I suppose not, since Immer works with regular JS objects.

Have I missed something essential?
I'm really frustrated. Need preserved order + speedy lookups. Arrays are too slow for lookups, so it stands between Map and Immutable.Map, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the Immutable library is native ES6 `Object.freeze()`. Note however this is a shallow freeze, so may need to be called recursively for a deep freeze. This provides runtime protection against mutating objects.

- https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/creating-immutable-objects-in-native-javascript/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Then the onus is on the developer to use non-mutating syntax for object manipulation. ES6 provides the object spread operator.

- https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator

```
const immutable = Object.freeze({ "question": "why?" })
const copy      = { ...immutable, "answer": 42 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this solves any of my issues. I need an iterable map with preserverd order that I can clone to get new reference and non mutated data.

Comment: Immutable.js has its own class model which can only be manipulated through its own internal functions. Immer is really just a utility library that allows you to modify native arrays/objects using mutating syntax on a proxy object in a wrapper function.

The native ES6 approach using the spread operator, provides a syntax for defining new objects inline without mutation. This doesn't propergate `Object.freeze()` (so you may need to explicitly add this for newly created objects for runtime enforcement), but you can still use libraries like lodash for iteration using functional programming.